# Using shared memory in a threads

Tags: c, multithreading, shared-memory

Hi i want to implement a client-server program that communicates with each other via shared  memory. in the server side i have two threads. a writer thread and a reader thread. the  writer thread puts some data into the queue and the reader thread reads from it and passes the data to the client side...

here is my reader thread ... the problem is that my two threads are created successfully but it does not get into the while loop i have specified in the thread routine... right now my question is: is it possible to work with shared memory in a thread routine when the
thread is called?

```
    void *reader_thread(void * id)
    {
        .....

        shm_addr = shmat(shm_id,NULL,0);

        if(shm_addr==(void *)-1)
        {
                    perror("shmat error");
            exit(1);
        }

        while (1)
        {   
            printf("Here in thread reader!");
            sem_wait(&queue_t->full);
            sem_wait(&queue_t->mutex);
            if (queue_t->tail != queue_t->head)
            {
                   memmove(imgPath,queue_t->imgAddr[queue_t->head],strlen(queue_t->imgAddr[queue_t->head])-1);
                imgPath[strlen(queue_t->imgAddr[queue_t->head])-1] = '\0';
                queue_t->head = (queue_t->head + 1) % QUEUE_SIZE;
             }  
            sem_post(&queue_t->mutex);
            sem_post(&queue_t->empty);

            ...
                sem_wait(&shared->shm_sem);
                memset(shm_addr,0,SHMSZ);
                memcpy(shm_addr, &imgPath, sizeof(imgPath));    
                sem_post(&shared->shm_sem);  

        }   
        return 0;
    }

///////////////////////////////


int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{

    pthread_t writer_t, reader_t;

    queue_t = (struct Queue*) malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    queue_t->head = 0;
    queue_t->tail = 0;

    sem_init(&queue_t->empty, 0, QUEUE_SIZE);
    sem_init(&queue_t->full, 1, 0);
    sem_init(&queue_t->mutex, 1, 1);

    shared = (struct shared_mem*) malloc(sizeof(shared_mem));
    sem_init(&shared->shm_sem, 1, 1);   

    int shmid;
    key_t key; 
    char *shm_addr; 
    key=1234;

    //Create the segment and set permissions.
    if ((shmid = shmget(key, SHMSZ, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) < 0)
    {
        perror("shmget error");
        if(errno==EEXIST)
                {
                        fprintf(stderr,"shared memory exist... ");
                        exit(1);
                }
    }
    fprintf(stdout,"shared mem created with id: %d\n",shmid);

    //Now we attach the segment to our data space.   
    if ((shm_addr = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)) == (char *) -1)
    {
        perror("shmat error");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Zero out memory segment
    memset(shm_addr,0,SHMSZ);

    if( pthread_create( &reader_t , NULL , reader_thread , &shmid) < 0)
    {
        perror("could not create reader thread");
        return 1;
    }

    pthread_detach(reader_t);
    puts("reader thread assigned");

    if( pthread_create( &writer_t , NULL , writer_thread , NULL) < 0)
    {
        perror("could not create writer thread");
        return 1;
    }
    pthread_detach( writer_t);
        puts("writer thread assigned");

    //if(shmdt(shm_addr) != 0)
          //      fprintf(stderr, "Could not close memory segment.\n");
    shmctl(shmid,IPC_RMID,NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it´s possible. did you create the shm? i only see the shmat, the Server should first create it, also the semaphore

Comment: yes i have created it in main function and pass shmid to reader thread

Comment: Am I right in thinking that at the end of main() you have detached the pthreads and destroyed the shared memory area... while the pthreads may or may not have started and may or may not have finished ?

Comment: your code part looks okay. the shmget command could be the problem. Can you post it? How do you get the shm_id from server to the client?

Comment: after running the program you can type `ipcs` in your terminal to see if the shm is created

Answer (score 0):

the previous problem had resolved... i replaced pthread_detach with pthread_join and put of at the end of main.
but rigt now i encountered segfault at client Side:[client get segmentation fault when attach to shared memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24774995/client-get-segmentation-fault-when-attach-to-shared-memory)

Comment: i think it's better to either present your solution as an answer by yourself or by an update to the original question. Your new question would be better posted as another (seperate) one, otherwise it's not visible as a question to the system and nobody will notice it...